# Detect network clients connect and disconnect

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, gateway

I have a linux gateway/server, which sharing PPPoE internet connection between network users.

Seeking for a proper way to detect when network clients are connected to and disconnected from the network and run a script on event occurs.

I have an **ISC DHCPD** server, and first idea was to trigger script using "*on commit*" and "*on release*"/"*on expiry*" DHCP events, but during researches, I got stuck, because **static leases** never triggering **expiry** or **release** events. "*on commit*" works fine by the way.

So I need a way to handle disconnect event (when client left the network) and trigger my script.

Any advice?

Comment: Seems you already have posted this question on serverfault right ? nevermind. Can you provide us the piece of your httpd.conf related to your triggered events ?

Comment: I asked a question in Serverfault dedicated to DHCPD static lease behavior. Now, as I stuck this DHCPD, I'm seeking for the alternatives.
I don't have apache installed, so I don't have a httpd.conf. I didn't get the point how httpd.conf can be involved here?

Comment: Sorry, i was talking about dhcpd.conf (not httpd.conf)...i apologize

Comment: Ah, okay. Anyway, why do you need my dhcpd.conf? It's very long and it's useless. **Static leases never triggering expiry or release events as per RFC**. So I'm seeking for **alternate method**

Comment: You could try monitoring arp messages. These are sent out alot, especially if an interface is 'new' to the local network it will spam requests at a pretty high rate, and will keep doing this while connected. Once you have not seen an arp request from a specific host for an amount of time you can assume it is offline.
As for a way of implementing this i cannot help alot (yet) - my scripting skills are not very good in *nix. But should be doable using libpcap.

Comment: This is **somewhat acceptable** but this requires constantly monitoring instead of event triggering. Anyway thanks for it, this will be my plan "B", if will not find anything more useful.

Comment: Part of the problem you will have here is that "connect and disconnect" are not well defined here. Having a static DHCP lease, what does it mean for a client to "disconnect?" To power down? To pull the network cable? What signal would the server use to know the client is "disconnected?" What is this "disconnect event" you speak of?

Comment: @StevenKath, As far as host goes down in any reason (ethernet cable issue, power off, client explosion) I need to somehow catch it in reasonably short amount of time (~5 min) and trigger a script.

Comment: @Greshnik okay, that is the problem with this "disconnect event" concept. As far as the server is concerned, there is no difference between the client exploding or simply having nothing to transmit for a few minutes. Since ethernet link state info doesn't propagate beyond the switch/WAP/etc, there is *no event* observable by the server. You have to implement some monitoring or probing and invent a "disconnected" condition based on that.

Comment: @Jake, Thanks for your support. Currently I'm using cron'ed (5 min interval) arping (max 5 requests, 2 seconds total timeout, quit on first) script. Not the best, but definitely working solution.

Comment: @Greshnik, glad to hear! It is indeed a crude way of checking, but it is the only thing that springs to mind in this scenario.